# Software Updater Log 13.04

Tags: updates, 13.04, log

I ran the Software Updater and noticed a message which indicated that my system may be broken and to run a certain command to fix it.  Of course I missed the command and even more strange, the Software Updater indicated all updates were installed.

To no avail, I have been perusing various logs trying to find the problem and the specific command Software Updater indicated I should run.  Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to find this error and the fix that was suggested?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was probably `sudo apt-get install -f` if you were using this install of 13.04 since beta you will need to run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`

Comment: I'm not running 13.04 beta, I am running Gnome Ubuntu 13.04 final. I ran both commands which returned the message (0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded).

Comment: give `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` a try; BTW beta would become final after the release date

Comment: I apologize, but I seem to be missing your point.  I understand that Beta would become final after the release date.

Comment: To clarify, I ran the upgrade command and it wanted to install the kernel upgrade only from earlier in the week as I am running kernel 3.9.2. I blocked that upgrade using Synaptic.  This brings me back to my earlier question:  Is it possible to determine from a log file what the error was that I received.  I have a feeling you know much more about this stuff than I do.  Thanks.

Comment: you may be able to get the error message from that last command if nit the error is likely fixed, check in this folder for logs `/var/log/apt/`

Comment: found it under term.log:  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache - that command with root does not work.  shrug ;)

Comment: I have no idea what that error message means...